# BindingGenerator - Syntax Error when building

Tags: java, c#, xamarin

I am trying to build a Binding Library (.AAR binding) and keep getting error as listed below:

> 1>BINDINGSGENERATOR : error (37: 14): Syntax error, expected: #PCDATA, , , , , {@code, {@docRoot}, {@inheritDoc}, {@link, {@linkplain, {@literal, {@value}, {@value, UnknownHtmlElementStart, @author, @apiSince, @deprecated, @deprecatedSince, @exception, @param, @return, @see, @serialData, @serialField, @since, @throws, @[unknown], @version

To replicate the issue follow the steps [Binding an .AAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-an-aar).

The `.AAR` file, doc and sources are coming from [Gecko Nightly Build](https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/geckoview-nightly/90.0.20210420095122/) `geckoview-nightly-90.0.20210420095122.aar`, `geckoview-nightly-90.0.20210420095122-javadoc.jar` and  `geckoview-nightly-90.0.20210420095122-sources.jar`

Target Framework: `Android 10.0(Q)` (I've tried against 9.0 as well, no luck)

*Here's a screenshot of the error's I am getting, nothing other than the `BINDINGSGENERATOR` errors.

[image]

Has anyone else came across such issues when building a Bindings Library from a `.AAR` file?

---

### **EDIT PER COMMENT**

**Version Information**

- VS Version: 16.10.4
- Xamarin.Android.SDK Version: 11.3.0.4
- Xamarin Version: 16.10.000.234

**Steps To Reproduce**

1. Create a new project (Android Bindings Library Xamarin C#)
2. Navigate to [Mozilla Maven](https://maven.mozilla.org/?prefix=maven2/org/mozilla/geckoview/geckoview-nightly/93.0.20210823092315/) and download `geckoview-nightly-93.0.20210823092315.aar`, `geckoview-nightly-93.0.20210823092315-sources.jar` and `geckoview-nightly-93.0.20210823092315-javadoc.jar` files.
3. Move the 3 files to the `Jars` directory and include them in the project (you may need to unblock the files through the files properties). Here's what my `Jars` directory looks like:[image]
4. Set Build Action for files as follows: `javadoc.jar` => `JavaDocJar` `sources.jar` => `JavaSourceJar` and `.aar` => `LibraryProjectZip`
5. Rebuild Solution (you should see at least 5 errors) for example: `BINDINGSGENERATOR : Syntax error` along those lines.

Comment: Which aar are you using?How can we reprduce this problem? Could you please post the steps?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT I hope my update makes the post clearer, thank you.

Comment: Do you actually need the javadoc? To me it kind of looks like it fails with javadoc related things.

Comment: @Cheesebaron more than likely not, if I exclude the javadoc, would this have any impact on creating the bindings I need?

Comment: Looks to me they are optional. I just tried on my machine with only the aar. It seems to build.

Comment: I was a bit quick there, chose the wrong target for the AAR. At least I am getting different errors now that those java doc you got. You may likely need to tweak this through the Metadata transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I spent some time getting the binding working for this. I added the following to the Metadata.xml file to make it bind.

```xml
<metadata>
    <remove-node path="/api/package[contains(@name,'org.mozilla.thirdparty')]" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/field[@name='mWindow']" />
    <remove-node path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='RuntimeSettings.Builder']/method[@name='newSettings' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1]]" />

    <!-- Because of interfaces contain const fields Xamarin generate abstract classes, which clash with property name. Renaming properties -->
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='getHistoryDelegate' and count(parameter)=0]" name="propertyName">SessionHistoryDelegate</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='setHistoryDelegate' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.HistoryDelegate']]" name="propertyName">SessionHistoryDelegate</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='getNavigationDelegate' and count(parameter)=0]" name="propertyName">SessionNavigationDelegate</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='setNavigationDelegate' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.NavigationDelegate']]" name="propertyName">SessionNavigationDelegate</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='getPermissionDelegate' and count(parameter)=0]" name="propertyName">SessionPermissionDelegate</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='setPermissionDelegate' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.PermissionDelegate']]" name="propertyName">SessionPermissionDelegate</attr>

    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='getSelectionActionDelegate' and count(parameter)=0]" name="propertyName">SessionSelectionActionDelegate</attr>
    <attr path="/api/package[@name='org.mozilla.geckoview']/class[@name='GeckoSession']/method[@name='setSelectionActionDelegate' and count(parameter)=1 and parameter[1][@type='org.mozilla.geckoview.GeckoSession.SelectionActionDelegate']]" name="propertyName">SessionSelectionActionDelegate</attr>
</metadata>
```

The `remove-node` can be explained as:

1. First `remove-node` removes some internals that you won't use anyways. So no need to create bindings for that.
2. Second one remove the field `mWindow` that for some reason was exposed publicly. I just removed it, we could also change visibility.
3. Third one I was not 100% sure how to fix. The `RuntimeSettings` class contains a `NewSettings` method that differened between `RuntimeSettings` and the builder in the generated code. I just opted to remove it.
4. The renaming of generated property names is due to a Java 8 feature where you can have `static` fields in a Interface in Java. This will generate an abstract class in the generated code. This class name clashed with the property name generated for the Setter/Getter for these delegates.

This makes the bindings build. I then added a simple sample project with the following code in the MainActivity to just show something on the screen:

```cs
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            
        var geckoView = new GeckoView(this);
        geckoView.LayoutParameters = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MatchParent);
        SetContentView(geckoView);

        var session = new GeckoSession();
        GeckoRuntime runtime = GeckoRuntime.Create(this);
        session.Open(runtime);

        geckoView.Session = session;

        session.LoadUri("https://blog.ostebaronen.dk");
    }
}
```

Everything builds but now it crashes at runtime claiming to be missing `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor`. Not sure if this aar needs some additional dependencies, which need to be added when binding.

EDIT:

I checked the POM of the version of GeckoView you linked to, no traces of SnakeYAML. However, the latest version found (93.0.20210825095400) does have it:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
  <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
  <version>1.24</version>
</dependency>
```

It also has some other dependencies it will need at runtime. Install the following NuGet packages in the binding project:

- Xamarin.AndroidX.Annotation
- Xamarin.AndroidX.Legacy.Support.V4
- Xamarin.AndroidX.Lifecycle.Extensions

Additionally, download the `.jar` file for SnakeYAML 1.24 (the android one) and add as a `EmbeddedReferenceJar`: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.24/

[image]

After you've done this it runs!

[image]

Comment: This is great work, thank you! It seems my issue was indeed my `Metadata` file being messed up, I've got it to build with your help. I will dig further into the `org.yaml.snakeyaml.constructor.Constructor` issue, not sure right now.

Comment: See my updated answer. Got it to run. Just needed to add some dependencies GeckoView requires at runtime.

Comment: You can grab the full project here: https://github.com/Cheesebaron/GeckoViewBinding

Comment: Thank you again @Cheesebaron appreciate your time on this. I've got everything working as I need now.

Comment: Good to know! Now about that bounty ( ͡~ ͜ʖ ͡°)

Comment: @Chessebaron I will give bounty when I am allowed, you have to wait ~24hrs in order to give it. As of this time, about another 4hrs and I can award it.